# Аналог category_and (WP) в sql-запросе

Tags: sql, wordpress

В Wordpress есть такой параметр для цикла как category_and, который позволяет вывести все посты, **входящие сразу в две категории одновременно**.

У меня цикл оформлен в виде sql-запроса. Каково будет условие-аналог для параметра category_and?

Сейчас у меня стоит условие, например:

```
WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN (1,3)
```

Но это выводит посты, относящиеся к первой категории, а потом ко второй.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такой запрос к моей базе выдал ровно 1 пост, который входит в категории 1 и 26 одновременно:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `object_id` FROM `wp_term_relationships`
WHERE `object_id`IN (
    SELECT `object_id` FROM `wp_term_relationships` WHERE `term_taxonomy_id`=26
) AND `object_id` IN (
    SELECT `object_id` FROM `wp_term_relationships` WHERE `term_taxonomy_id`=1
)
```